# Push notification alert not working on iOS 7 but it does on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I want to implement push notifications in my app.

In iOS 8, at the app launch, the user gets the classic "Would you like app to send notifications?", but in iOS 7 it doesn't work and I fail to understand why.

This is the code I'm using

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

In iOS 8 it works pretty much, but iOS 7 doesn't.

Any clue why is this not working?

I made and use all the necessary certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good only but try using the below [trick](http://corinnekrych.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html):-

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0  
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {  
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];  
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];  
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  
    } else {  
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];  
    }  
#else  
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];  
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried but doesn't work either. I've also reset the simulator, but none works.